# First attempt at DFF VHDL

Tags: vhdl

I'm fairly new to VHDL and was wondering if anyone could have a look at the code I constructed for a DFF. I haven't added the reset or preset on as of yet. Just the basic function. Also don't have the software at home to test it on so I'm going by your guys experience that its fine!

```
LIBRARY ieee;
USE ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
USE ieee.std_logic_arith.all;

ENTITY dff IS
    PORT(
        D:  IN  std_logic;  --data in
        CLK:    IN  std_logic;  --clock in
        Q:  OUT std_logic   --data out
    );

END dff;

ARCHITECTURE rtl OF dff IS
BEGIN
    process(CLK)
        BEGIN
            if (rising_edge(CLK)) then
                Q <= D;
            end if;
    END process;
END rtl;
```

Comment: Apart from losing std_logic_arith, all I would do is lose the unnecessary clutter and write `if rising_edge(CLK) then` - this is not your father's C compiler...

Answer (score 1):

You could try ghdl which is available for Windows, OS X, Linux and likely Free BSD.  (And you can comment out the -- `USE ieee.std_logic_arith.all;` )

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity dff_tb is

end entity dff_tb;

architecture behaviour of dff_tb is
-- component instantion leaves the possibility of a configuration specification
component dff   
    port (
        d:      in  std_logic;
        clk:    in  std_logic;
        -- rst:    in  std_logic;
        q:      out std_logic
    );
end component dff;

     signal d:      std_logic := '0';
     signal clk:    std_logic := '0';
     -- signal rst:    std_logic := '1';
     signal q:      std_logic;
begin
DUT: work
       port map (
         d => d,
         clk => clk,
--         rst => rst,
         q => q
       );

-- Stimulus:

CLOCK:           
    process     
    begin        
        wait for 20 ns;
        clk <= not clk;
        if Now > 400 ns then  -- stop clock after stmulus expires
            wait;
        end if;
    end process CLOCK;

-- RESET:
--     process
--     begin
--         wait for 60 ns;
--         rst <= '0';
--         wait;           -- done with reset
--     end process RESET;
--     
DATA:
    process
    begin
        wait for 80 ns;
        d <= '1';
        wait for 40 ns;
        d <= '0';
        wait for 80 ns;
        d <= '1';
        wait for 120 ns;
        d <= '0';
        wait for 40 ns;
        wait;
    end process DATA;
end behaviour;
```

I borrowed this from a nearly identical effort with a reset.

> ghdl -a dff.vhdl   # includes appended test bench code above
>
> ghd -e dff_tb
>
> ghdl -r dff_tb --wave=dff_tb.ghw
>
> gtkwave dff_tb.ghw

( setup signal display), yields:

[image]

There's nothing wrong with your D flip flop.

Answer (score 0):

For the software, you could use Altera Quartus. It's meant specifically for the Altera boards, but it is free and has nifty simulation tools to help you test your VHDL code pretty easily. There's even a free version of it. (I used that to learn VHDL)